# How can I use t24 format to send SOAP request

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I am working with Java Web Services. I got a task to create web service which will send the SOAP request in following format.

```
 <CreateAccount>
    <field name="name">xyz abc</field>
    <field name="dob">1989-04-05</field>
    <field name="phone">9999999999</field>
    <field name="address">vvk</field>
</CreateAccount>
```

I created the WSDL file with types section like

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="abc">
  <xsd:element name="CreateAccount">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="field" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="0">
              <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                  <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="name" use="required"/>
                  </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
              </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
         </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

But when I try to open WSDL url, it show

> Fault - makeTypeElement() was told to create a type "{../XYZService/}>>CreateAccount>field", with no containing element

I tried Googling but not get the proper result. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your attribute element as below. 
`<xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="name" use="required" />`

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
I think its a bug with Axis. I tried it with Axis2, it is working fine.